# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, registry

I am trying to launch automatically my application when I turn on the computer. I've wrote this program into my code :

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(_param.AUTOMATIC_LAUNCH) == 1)
{
    registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    registryKey.SetValue("XXX", Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.ToString());
}
if (Convert.ToInt32(_param.AUTOMATIC_LAUNCH) == 0 && registryKey != null)
{
    registryKey.DeleteValue("XXX", true);
}
```

The key is indeed in the folder :  "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run".
But I have a this message which appears in my log :

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\XXXXXX.ini' denied.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> (....)

I've tried to grant autorization to the user in the folder of my application but it doesn't work. In addition, the "config-borne.ini" is a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you run your application as administrator?

Comment: Hello, yes I run it as administrator

Comment: @harili, based on my test, I can set the value successfully. Then, where do you see the error, do you throw a exception or other else?  I suggest that you can put your app in D disk to have a try.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Hello, I can also set the key successfully. When I turn on the computer (to test if the app is going to launch itself alone), the exception abore appears. Yes I throw an exception and I've try to ad a pop-up which suggests you to run the app with administrator access, but no success. Then I am going to try to put it into my D:.

Comment: I believe this is a problem with a temporary environment variable not being set and something defaulting to c:\windows which your program doesn't have access to. I have the same problem but I can't figure out which environment variable it's using.

Comment: a ha. one of these... TMP TEMP USERPROFILE ... https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10779#issuecomment-408306217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I got a solution but it's a little different. I didn't create a key in the registry due to the lack of autorization. To overcome this problem, I choose to create a shortcut directly in the startup folder (CTRL+R and shell:startup if you want to see it).